# Accordion Table + Date Range Picker + AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, accordion, daterangepicker

I am trying to change the inside of a DIV when the date in the Date Range Picker is changed. I am using [Date Range Picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/), and [Accordion Table](https://codepen.io/jopico/pen/EGpim) to help with this page.

The DIV contains an accordion table that changes to show a different date range of data when the date range picker is used to select a different date range. When the table regenerates, it will no longer open and close like an accordion section.

This is the HTML/PHP on my page that generates the table and date range picker:

```
<!-- Date selector -->
<div id="reportrange">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>
    <span></span>
</div>

<!-- Our table -->
<div id="replace">
    <?php
        $yesterday = date("m/d/Y", strtotime('-31 hours'));
        table($yesterday, $yesterday);
    ?>
</div>
```

At the bottom of the page I have all the information for the date range picker along with the AJAX call to call the table() function. Here is the AJAX call:

```
// AJAX call to our php function which creates the table
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/jstranslator.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'action': 'table', 'start': begin, 'stop': stop},
    success:function(result){
        document.getElementById("replace").innerHTML = result;
    },
    error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
    }
});
```

I need help figuring out why my table will no longer open/close once the data is regenerated. If you inspect the page and look at the contents you can see that the table is full of all the data you just can't see it!

Comment: Ah, I'm guessing the Accordion Table library ties its events to the original table, which you then 'replace' with the ajax return table. I don't know Accordion Table's methods, but there may be something in it to 're-apply events' to the new table.

Comment: Side Note: Instead of doing `document.getElementById("replace").innerHTML = result;` you can use jquery style: `$("#replace").html( result );`... but that wont solve the issue of the original Accordion events being lost on replace.

Comment: You actually helped me solve my problem thank you! I didn't think about re-initializing the table. I just added the script to make the table open and close at the end of the success: statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to those who helped!

My issue was that the js event was tied to the original table. So aall I had to do was add the javascript which made the table open and close to the end of the ajax success statement.

```
/* When the date range is changed, update the table
 */
$('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    var begin = picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    var stop = picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');

    // AJAX call to our php function which creates the table
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/jstranslator.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'action': 'table', 'start': begin, 'stop': stop},
        success:function(result){
            document.getElementById("replace").innerHTML = result;
            $(function(){
                $(".fold-table tr.view").on("click", function(){
                    $(this).toggleClass("open").next(".fold").toggleClass("open");
                });
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Glad you got it! Lost events always tend to rear its ugly head from time to time.... especially with how fun it is to grab new data with ajax and the like :)